# Convert today in python to 'YYYY-MM-DD' but keep the format as datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to subtract 2 datetime columns to find difference between th two. One is today's date and the other has date ion the format 'YYY-MM-DD'.
df['A']-df['today']

If I try to convert today's date in the same format using:
`current_date=datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, it gets converted into a string and the date difference operation doesn't happen.
Error I get is-
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.date'

Any help is much apprecaited

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

```
#The method to_datetime will infer the date type
df = pd.DataFrame({"date1": ['2020-01-10'],
                   "date2": ['2020-01-15']})

df["date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date1"], infer_datetime_format=True)
df["date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date2"], infer_datetime_format=True)

df["test"] = df["date2"] - df["date1"]

#output
#|   date1    |    date2    |  test  |
#| 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-15  | 5 days |
```